# Stop words list to use for CountVectorization

Tags: scikit-learn, naive-bayes-algorithim

The sci-kit learn library by defaults provides two options either no stop words 
or one can specify stop_words=english to include a list of predefined English words
I am using Naive Bayes for SMS spam detection. Is there any other list of stop words
I can experiment with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
print(stopwords.words('english'))
```

Comment: Thanks. Apart from stopwords is there any other thing that can be changed when using text classification using Naive Bayes?

Comment: You can do stemming, lematization. See nltk library for more use. If you want some sophisticated analysis you can see spacy.

Comment: Thanks. I will check that out. I found something interesting using the nltk increased the accuracy. Also I am currently using the dataset from `https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/sms-spam-collection-dataset` I feel it's too small to train and test. Is there any place else I could get the data for SMS spam?

Comment: Search kaggle dataset directory. There are tons of dataset there.

Comment: I searched in Kaggle dataset but it seems it's the same repeated dataset from UCI Machine Learning Repository